# Retrieve data from database in CakePHP

Tags: php, database, cakephp, data-retrieval

I have a database with two tables: users and mails.

In my MailsController.php controller I have a function `history()`:

```
 public function history() {
 $mails = $this->Mail->find('id');
 $this->set('mails', $mails);
 $result = $this->Mail->find('fromUsername');
 foreach($result as $row){
    $this->set('mails', $row);
 } 
}
```

My goal is to print on the page all `$mails` sent by this username. But in case I do this, I do not know what code should I put in the `history.ctp` page.

Can you please help me a bit?

`fromUserame` in the column where I save the usernames in the 'mails' table of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MailsController.php:history() you sent the variable `$mails` to your view (history.ctp).

In your view, you can access `$mails` as you would any other PHP variable. Since this will be an array, you will want to use a loop to display the data:

```
foreach ($mails as $mail) {
    echo $mail['Mail']['fromUsername']; // Modify according to your data and required output.
}
```

To see what $mails contains in your script (for debugging purposes), you can dump its contents:

```
var_dump($mails);
```

Comment: this prints out all data of the database. What should i include in my code to print out data only from the specific user?